# How to insert PHP inside Javascript inside HTML inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following script who list some sql values in a table

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))  {

            $idOfUrl = $row['2'];

            echo("<tr onclick='window.location.href = \"


// how can i insert here a  php value ? --> $idOfUrl

                \"';>");
            echo("<td>");
            echo $row['1'];
            echo("</td>");
            echo ("</tr>"); 
            echo("</a>");
            }
```

I want to make the entire row  clickable to a page with an ID whos from the SQL table.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: you should learn about server side languages (php for example) and client side (javascript for example). To run php as you want you need to use ajax

Comment: You just paste it there where you want it: `echo("<tr onclick='window.location.href = \"$idOfUrl\"';>");`

Comment: The same way you did with `echo $row['1'];`

Comment: @LelioFaieta tho you're right about learning the difference between server side and client side, here is not the case because he has the id in php and echos just the javascript. So he needs just to concatenate the id of the URL to the string.

Comment: @edwin the easy way doesn't mean it's the right way

Comment: @LelioFaieta do you really mean that you would do an ajax for this case?

Answer (score 0):

you want to insert a PHP variable while you are in PHP. this is very simple:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))  {

    $idOfUrl = $row['2'];

    echo("<tr onclick='window.location.href = ".$idOfUrl."';>");
    echo("<td>");
    echo $row['1'];
    echo("</td>");
    echo ("</tr>"); 
    echo("</a>");
}
```

Comment: thank you bro ! theses "." were missing !

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo("<tr onclick='window.location.href=".$idOfUrl."';>");
```

or

```
echo("<tr onclick='window.location.href=\"$idOfUrl\"';>");
```

maybe thats hope you